# Mouseleave function overwrites the click function JQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, hover

the mouseleave function in my code overwrites the click function. 
What I want to do:
If an image is selected (opacity 1.0) then should the hover function only work on the other 2 elements (not on the selected one).

this is my html

```
<div id="hover"><img src="http://www.franz-sales-verlag.de/fsvwiki/uploads/Lexikon/Baum.jpg" width="100px;" /></div>

<div id="hover1"><img src="http://www.franz-sales-verlag.de/fsvwiki/uploads/Lexikon/Baum.jpg" width="100px;"/></div>

<div id="hover2"><img src="http://www.franz-sales-verlag.de/fsvwiki/uploads/Lexikon/Baum.jpg" width="100px;"/></div>
```

my jquery

```
$("#hover").mouseover(function(){
        $("#hover").fadeTo(100, 1.0);
});

$("#hover").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#hover").fadeTo(100, 0.7);
});

$("#hover1").mouseover(function(){
    $("#hover1").fadeTo(100, 1.0);
});

$("#hover1").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#hover1").fadeTo(100, 0.7);
});

$("#hover2").mouseover(function(){
    $("#hover2").fadeTo(100, 1.0);
});

$("#hover2").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#hover2").fadeTo(100, 0.7);
});

$("#hover").click(function(){
        $("#hover").fadeTo(100, 1.0);
    $("#hover1").fadeTo(100, 0.7);
    $("#hover1").fadeTo(100, 0.7);
});

$("#hover1").click(function(){
    $("#hover1").fadeTo(100, 1.0);
    $("#hover").fadeTo(100, 0.7);
    $("#hover2").fadeTo(100, 0.7);
});

$("#hover2").click(function(){
    $("#hover2").fadeTo(100, 1.0);
    $("#hover").fadeTo(100, 0.7);
    $("#hover1").fadeTo(100, 0.7);
});
```

here is a jsfiddle:
[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSteinel/3QLC6/)

I hope someone can help me.
thanks in advance!

Comment: You should really refactoring your code, could be done in less than 10 lines

Comment: What do you mean by "after click the hover function should only work on the other 2 elements"

Comment: Your'e are saying that after you click one image, the image (div) won't suffer the effects of mouseleave and mouseover until you refresh the page?

Comment: I am sorry, but i am new to this, how can I do it in less than 10 lines? Yes, if I click the first image, it should stay selected with an opacity 1.0, so there is no hover effect on the selected image. The other images should fade to opacity 0.7 on mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this http://jsfiddle.net/3QLC6/5/

```
$("#hover1,#hover2").fadeTo(100, 0.7);

$("#hover, #hover1, #hover2").mouseover(function () {
   $(this).fadeTo(100, 1.0);
});

$("#hover,#hover1,#hover2").mouseleave(function () {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {$(this).fadeTo(100, 0.7)};
});

$("#hover,#hover1,#hover2").click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('selected').fadeTo(100, 1.0).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected').fadeTo(100, 0.7);
});
```

Also see update with class usage: http://jsfiddle.net/3QLC6/6/

Comment: Yeah, really easy coding! I am able to read it :-)...Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome.. Happy to be Helpful... :)

Answer (score 2):

I've made some code refactoring for you.

```
<div class="hover-img"><img src="http://www.franz-sales-verlag.de/fsvwiki/uploads/Lexikon/Baum.jpg" width="100px;" />hover</div>
<div class="hover-img"><img src="http://www.franz-sales-verlag.de/fsvwiki/uploads/Lexikon/Baum.jpg" width="100px;"/>hover1</div>
<div class="hover-img"><img src="http://www.franz-sales-verlag.de/fsvwiki/uploads/Lexikon/Baum.jpg" width="100px;"/>hover2</div>
```

And simple code:

```
//select all image containers
var hoverContainers = $('.hover-img');
//initial fade out
hoverContainers.css('opacity', 0.7);
//mouseover and mouseleave binding
hoverContainers.hover(
  //mouseover
  function(){    
    $(this).fadeTo(100, 1);
  },
  //mouseleave
  function(){
    //check if you image has 'selected' class
    if (!$(this).is('.selected'))
      //if no fade out
      $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.7);
  }
);
//add 'selected' class on click
hoverContainers.click(function(){
  //remove 'selected' class from previously selected image
  hoverContainers.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected').fadeTo(100, 0.7);
  //mark clicked image with 'selected' class
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QLC6//) with code

Best regards

**Edit**
I forgot to fade out previously selected image.

```
//add 'selected' class on click
hoverContainers.click(function(){
  //remove 'selected' class from previously selected image
  hoverContainers.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected').fadeTo(100, 0.7);
  //mark clicked image with 'selected' class
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

The following code will do the magic:
    hoverContainers.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected').fadeTo(100, 0.7);

Test updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/3QLC6/7/

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! But it is hard for me to understand the code. So I am not able to refine the code. I would like to have that there can be only one image at the same time selected. Is it possible to add this function?